# move fake cursor to position taken from clicked character

Tags: javascript, cursor-position

I have a div with text using monospace font, and I need to display a cursor in the place where I click, I have functions that display text with cursor:

```
  function draw() {
    var text = textarea.val();
    var html;
    if (pos == text.length) {
      html = encode(text) + '<span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span>';
    } else {
      html = encode(text.slice(0, pos)) + '<span class="cursor">' +
        encode(text[pos+1]) + '</span>' + encode(text.slice(pos+1));
    }
    output.html(html);
  }
```

and function that get cursor position based on x/y coordinate of the mouse event:

```
function get_char_pos(div, text, event) {
  var num_chars = get_num_chars(div);
  var cursor = div.find('.cursor');
  var rect = cursor[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  var width = rect.width;
  var height = rect.height;
  var offset = div.offset();
  var col = Math.floor((event.pageX-offset.left)/width);
  var row = Math.floor((event.pageY-offset.top)/height);
  var try_pos = col + (row > 0 ? num_chars * row : 0);
  return try_pos;
}
```

It almost working except when text contain tabs (tabs are replaced by 4 spaces by encode function). I've try to fix tabs using this:

```
  var before = text.slice(0, try_pos);
  var tabs = before.match(/\t/g);
  var fix = tabs ? tabs * 3 : 0;
  try_pos += fix;
  return try_pos > text.length ? text.lenght : try_pos;
```

but this don't work. It should also work for a case when I click on space that may be part of tab. How to fix it when text contain tabs?

Here is [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/jyKEPj?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab character is the issue. It's a single character which means the string it's not calculated as four characters in the text.slice. If you replace \t with four spaces your issue is solved.

Comment: Fixed the issue by replacing \t by \x00\x00\x00\x00 and after slice replacing it back to \t to get the length and removing \x00 that left at the end, if use click in the middle of the tab.